# facet_grid() and color condition

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, facet-grid

I have some questions about visualization. I have dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Campaign = c('month 10', 'month 11','month 10', 'month 11','month 10', 'month 11'),
  name = c('TI', 'TI', 'SI', 'SI', 'NPS', 'NPS'),
  values = c(93,96,83,84, 43,36))
```

I need to set colors by condition:

```
ifelse(df$values>95,'green',ifelse(df$values>90,'yellow','red'))
```

I had try three different version , and all of them don’t work correct.

```
1.
p <- ggplot(df, aes(name,values, group = Campaign))+
geom_bar(stat = 'identity',aes(fill = factor(name)))+
facet_grid(.~Campaign)
p + scale_fill_manual(values = paste(ifelse(df$values>
      95,'green',ifelse(df$values>90, 'yellow',' red'))))+

2. cols <-ifelse(df$values>95,'green',ifelse(df$values>90,'yellow','red'))
p + scale_fill_manual(values = cols)

3. df$color <- ifelse(df$values>95,'green',ifelse(df$values>90,'yellow','red'))
p + scale_fill_manual(values = paste(df$color))
and this:
p + scale_fill_manual(values = unique(as.character(df$color)))
```

Then I use facet_grid() my color condition doesn’t work correctly. But it works well without using facet_grid(). What is wrong?

Comment: `df$fill.group = cut(df$values, breaks=c(-Inf, 90, 95, Inf))`. Then, `ggplot(df, aes(name,values, group = Campaign, fill=fill.group)) + ... + scale_fill_manual(values=c("red", "yellow", "green")`. Also, (1) remove `fill=factor(name)` since it looks like you want to fill by ranges of `values`, (2) if you're faceting on `Campaign` then there's no need for `group=Campaign`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this,

```
df$fill.group = cut(df$values, breaks=c(-Inf, 90, 95, Inf))             

# install.packages(c("tidyverse"), dependencies = TRUE)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(name,values, fill=fill.group)) + 
       geom_bar(stat = 'identity') + facet_grid(.~Campaign) +
       scale_fill_manual(values=c("red", "yellow", "green")
      )
```

[image: dd]

Comment: Thanks a lot for solution.

Comment: Glad if it was helful. If your question has been answered it's helpful to others if you maker it as answered. That way other people, who has a similar question, can find a good answer.